# How to find element - SAP NetWeaver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using SAP NetWeaver (SAP WEB UI) and found it difficult to automate with selenium.

I can say that a big amount of objects' Id's\Names are actually being changed from one-page reloading to another. 
So I have tried to use `_webDriver.FIndElement(By.Xpath(//*[contains(@id,'foo')]))`;
But the element cannot be found. While this (find an element by XPath) can work on one object, it won't work for a different one. very frustrating. 
It might be that either I'm doing something wrong or the object rendered is problematic. 
This is an example for an HTML object :

```html
<input id="grid#28.115#7,1#if" ct="I" lsdata="{0:'grid\x2328.115\x237,1\x23if',2:'100000008',4:10,8:true,9:true,13:'100\x25',14:'FORCEDLEFT',17:true,18:true,19:true,20:'0',25:true,41:false,44:{MaxInputLen:'10'}}" lsevents="{FieldHelpPress:[{ClientAction:'none'},{modalNo:'0',rgv:[{id:'28.115',submit:'X',type:'GuiGridView'}]}]}" type="text" maxlength="10" tabindex="-1" ti="-1" class="lsTblEdf3 lsTblEdf3NoEllipsis urBorderBox lsControl--explicitwidth lsField__input" readonly="true" value="100000008" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" name="grid#28.115#7,1#if" style="vertical-align:top;text-align:left;" title="">
```

That's the way I'm trying to find it , but being failed:

```
  var element = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id,'115#7,1')]")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `ExpectedConditions`. See code below.

```
var elem = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.CssSelector("input[id*='115#7,1']")));
```

Comment: it doesn't work. 
please note that the element's full id is : `grid#28.115#7,1#if`

Comment: Yes, `InvalidSelectorException`

Comment: @YanivEliav it is impossible. Can you recheck if your code is typo?